# Laravel Eloquent: Multiple Foreign Keys from One Primary Key

Tags: laravel

I am in-progress to create a project in Laravel.
I have two Database Table, which is created by migrations:
I want to setup multiple foreign key in database schema.

1. Table User

```
Schema::create('tr_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->string('password');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('departement_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('departement_id')
                ->references('id_departement')->on('tr_departements')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

2. Table Departrements

```
Schema::create('tr_departements', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_departement');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('created_by')
                ->references('id')->on('tr_users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('updated_by')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('updated_by')
                ->references('id')->on('tr_users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

What I want to know is how to describe relation in Models?

*Edit:*
My plan to use this relation is every users is belongs to departement, and any departement has many users, and every users has only one departement

Comment: can you provide information on how you plan to use this relation? does a user belong to a department? are there multiple users in one department? can a user belong to more than one department?

Comment: thx for response, please check the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeking One-to-One relationship from user to department then relation would be like this:

In your User model code would be like this:

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Department');
}
```

And in your department model:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

For multiple relationship you can refer [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships) documentation

Comment: I've been think to create relation like this, is it wrong?
return $this->belongsTo(User::class, ['created_by', 'updated_by']);

Comment: @KautsarAlbana Use above one and it'll work as you are expecting.

Comment: Then how can I passing data to view via controller where controller get data from model

Comment: @KautsarAlbana use compact() method to do thAT